# CodeIgniter project showing too many redirect issue after uploading it on server

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect

I upload my admin panel on server which is in CodeIgniter. It is not in root, inside of a folder.

While I am executing it ,it is showing only the login page and after submitting login form, following error is generating.

In Mozilla:

> The page isn’t redirecting properly
>
> Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.
>
> This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.

In Chrome:

> The www.browzandbeauty.com.au page isn’t working
>
> www.browzandbeauty.com.au redirected you too many times.
>   Try clearing your cookies.
>   ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: chk your url or connection

Comment: sow how you are redirecting after login.

Comment: did you check this http://serverfault.com/questions/772398/codeigniter-website-have-too-many-redirects ?

Comment: issue may be related to .htaccess .. check that part in your CI stuff